# if-statement on different typeid's

Tags: c++, if-statement, types

I am currently working on a code and I am trying to use a if-statement on a variable which was taken from a .txt file with a basic string. Its supposed to look like

```
if (a.variable == "string") {}
```

When I use

```
std::cout << a.variable << std::endl;
std::cout << "string" << std::endl;
```

I get the same results but when using

```
std::cout << typeid(a.variable).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << typeid("string").name() << std::endl;
```

I get different results:

NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE

and

A5_c.

Could this be the reason why the if-statement failed? Unless I am incorrect, the first typeid stands for a basic string.
I am grateful for any input!

The code I use for reading it looks like:

```
std::string::size_type beginoption = section.find("=",position); 
beginoption = beginoption +1; 
std::string::size_type endoption = section.find("\n",position); 
optionstorage = section.substr(beginoption, endoption - beginoption);
```

Comment: Where is the `a.variable` value generated? You said that it's read from a text file, but where did the value come from when _writing_ that file?

Comment: The different results form typeid might be due to the fact that `"string"` is considered as having the type `char[]`, not `std::string`. Not sure though.

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), to be honest.  What is the high-level problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: `"string"` is of type `const char[7]`. There is no class named `"string"`, though there is a class with the identifier `::std::string`

Comment: The a.variable is taken from an optionsfile I wrote by hand before.  The code I use for reading it looks like:
```
 std::string::size_type beginoption = section.find("=",position);
                        beginoption = beginoption +1;
                        std::string::size_type endoption = section.find("\n",position);

                        optionstorage = section.substr(beginoption, endoption - beginoption);
```

Comment: But where is `a.variable` generated?

Comment: @Otrbit -- You didn't have to resort to use `typeid`.  Maybe `a.variable` is simply not equal to `"string"`.  There is practically no chance the compiler will get something like that wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two objects in C++ don't have to be the same type to compare as equal.  You *can* compare string objects to string literals because there is an `operator==` overload that accepts `std::string` and `char const *` arguments.  (The `typeid()` operator returns a different value because the two expressions have different types; one is a string object and the other is a char array -- but you can indeed still compare them.)

You mentioned that your "if statement is failing" but when you inspect the contents of the strings, they appear to be the same -- they may actually *not* be the same.  For example, in your code, if `a.variable` has trailing whitespace, you would *not* see this in the output and yet the strings would also not be equal.

Try writing both strings surrounded by some characters.  I suspect that you will see there is some extra whitespace somewhere:

```
std::cout << '[' << a.variable << ']' << std::endl;
std::cout << '[' << "string" << ']' << std::endl;
```

Consider also displaying `a.variable.size()`. If it's not 6, then the two strings cannot be equal since they have different lengths.

Comment: The Output generated is:
```
]cube
[cube]

```
Any Ideas what could cause this?

Comment: @Otrbit Terminal control characters in the string maybe? It's hard to say. Try outputting the character codes contained in the string?  `for (unsigned char c : a.variable) { std::cout << static_cast<int>(c) << ' '; }`

Comment: I checked the size of a.variable and its to long. Guess maybe there is infact a space included? I will check real quick.

Comment: the output for your code was: 99 117 98 101 13 Mesh type

Comment: @Otrbit Aha, 13 is a whitespace character (carriage-return), so it looks like you are reading a file with CRLF line endings in an environment that expects LF line endings. The CR character is therefore considered part of the data and is included in the read string.

Comment: You've got a carriage return in the first string.  It returns the "carriage" to the beginning of the line, so after writing 'cube' it moves to the beginning of the line and adds the ']'.

Comment: You guys are my heros.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of `typeid`, `a.variable` is of type `std::string` while the string literal `"string"` is of type `char const [7]`.

That explains the output of

```
std::cout << typeid(a.variable).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << typeid("string").name() << std::endl;
```